# Unable to use both timeout and mouseover

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to use setTimeout following a mouseover event, but my js within the ' jQuery(document).ready(function()' line never fires.

```
$('.employeejob').on('mouseover', function() {

     jQuery(document).ready(function() {

         setTimeout(function() {
        
                // some js

         }, 350); 
    
     });

});
```

Comment: Surely your document-ready should be outside of the event listener?

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work either :(

Comment: This code on its own works fine. You have some other issue. Try a console.log on the mouseover to see if the `on` event fires in the first place

Comment: Also note: what you are doing will add an additional timeout for every mouseover event. You may not want to do that

Comment: @Ant, yep, i've added a line imediately under the 'mouseover' line and logged it. The function fires on mouseover. Only part of the function that isn't working is the timeout

Comment: Ah, I was using $(this) within the settimeout function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use console log to debug where it breaks. It could be you have an unhandled error that gets fired and all other code in the script might not run. If not the below code should run as expected

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('Document is ready!');
  $('.employeejob').on('mouseover', function() {
      console.log('mouse over triggered');
         setTimeout(function() {
            // This code will run after 300ms
            console.log('timeout code');
         }, 1500); 
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="employeejob">
  <h1>Employee Job</h1>
</div>
```